# Significance of (smoothed) covariates in GAM model (R)

Tags: r, statistical-significance, poisson-distribution, generalized-additive-model

If I have the following GAM model using the `chicago` `gamair` dataset:

```
m1 <- gam(death~s(time,bs="cr",k=200)+s(pm10median,bs="cr")+
            s(so2median,bs="cr")+s(o3median,bs="cr")+s(tmpd,bs="cr"),
          data=chicago,family=poisson())
summary(m1)
```

How do I interpret the results below? Specifically, how can I tell whether the covariates are of significance and to what degree?

```
Family: poisson 
Link function: log 

Formula:
death ~ s(time, bs = "cr", k = 200) + s(pm10median, bs = "cr") + 
    s(so2median, bs = "cr") + s(o3median, bs = "cr") + 
    s(tmpd, bs = "cr")

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) 4.744645   0.001342    3534   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                  edf  Ref.df   Chi.sq p-value    
s(time)       167.933 187.535 1827.171  <2e-16 ***
s(pm10median)   6.863   7.695   14.480  0.0526 .  
s(so2median)    7.382   8.141    9.221  0.3415    
s(o3median)     1.579   1.985    1.916  0.3493    
s(tmpd)         8.270   8.850  105.360  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.361   Deviance explained = 39.8%
UBRE = 0.24107  Scale est. = 1         n = 4841
```

Usually, I would be able to look at the coefficients and see whether the estimates are having a positive or negative effect and see whether it is significant `(Pr(>|z|)`. But, when all I have are smoothed terms in the formula, how can I tell?

Do I look at the significance of smoothed terms? So `so2median` (well just barely) and `o3median` are not significant? What about time and tmpd? Do they have a positive or negative effect and to what magnitude/degree?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are fitting smooth functions, you need to plot the estimated functions to interpret the fitted model. Use `plot(m1, pages = 1)` to do that. This is the equivalent of looking at the coefficients.

Smooth terms either are or are not significant, given your chosen threshold for declaring significance. You seem to imply your threshold is 0.05 and hence only the smooths of `time` and `tmpd` would be considered *significantly* different from a flat or constant function given that threshold.

Comment: Are you saying that when plotting the functions, I can see whether they have a positive or negative effect (per your first paragraph)? Or, I can only tell if they're significant or not (and not whether they have a positive/negative effect) (per your second paragraph)?

Comment: The p value tells if the estimated function(s) provide evidence that is consistent with the null hypothesis (of a flat constant function) or not. If you want to distill that to “significant” interpret the p value as you would for any other term in a model. As for plotting, yes! Except it would be naive to assume only negative or positive effects; the estimated functions are smooth, nonlinear functions and could demonstrate positive effects over some part of the domain of the covariates and negative effects elsewhere. Also note that for good, technical reasons the estimated functions & hence

Comment: …the plots are centred about a value of 0. The model constant term, the intercept, is the overall mean of the response variable so the plots show where the covariates  would imply the response is above or below this overall average.

Comment: My second paragraph was based solely on the output you showed from the `summary()` output and looking at which p values are < 0.05

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, Gavin!